# Default Python interpreter type

Tags: python

Is the default Python interpreter which comes with Ubuntu distribution CPython or not?

If it is not CPython, does it have GIL or not?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the default Python interpreter implementation on Ubuntu, just like everywhere else, is CPython. If it were anything non-standard (e.g. PyPy, IronPython, Jython, Cython or whatever else), it would be named that. Plain "Python" is always CPython.

Regarding the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock), yes, CPython and therefore Ubuntu's standard Python interpreter is subject to that feature/limitation. That means your Python scripts will usually run in a single thread (unless you use the `multiprocessing` library or some other special stuff).